# java.lang.SecurityException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature: http://apache.org/xml/features/allow-java-encodings

Tags: tomcat

I have a tomcat web application written in Struts. It runs well in Linux with `Tomcat 7` and `Java 7`. When I migrated it to Windows 10 under `Tomcat8.5` and `Java 8`,
it throws a `SAXNOtREcognizedException` error and the application stops working:

> java.lang.SecurityException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature: http://apache.org/xml/features/allow-java-encodings

These are the jar files included under the application WEB-INF/lib folder:

```
activation.jar
BCEL.jar
bsf.jar
collections.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-dbcp.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-logging.jar
commons-pool.jar
commons-services.jar
commons-validator.jar
cos.jar
crimson.jar
DbConnectionBroker.jar
java_cup.jar
jaxp.jar
jdbc2_0-stdext.jar
jdom.jar
jdom-jdk11.jar
JLex.jar
log4j-1.2.7.jar
mailapi.jar
mysql_comp.jar
mysql.jar
ojdbc7.jar
regexp.jar
runtime.jar
smtp.jar
struts.jar
struts.jar--2
taglibs-request.jar
xalan.jar
xalansamples.jar
xalanservlet.jar
xercesImpl.jar
xerces.jar
xml-apis.jar
xsltc.jar
```

They have the same jar files in both Linux and Windows.

Someone suggested to add the bc4j-mbeans.jar, but I could not find where to download it. I tried to download the oc4j container, but there is no bc4j-mbeans.jar found.

Answer (score 6):

add the following properties to TOMCAT_HOME/conf/catalina.properties:

- javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
- javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
- javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
- javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl

[source](http://adfinmunich.blogspot.com/2013/04/exception-during-startup-from-tomcat-6.html)

Comment: Are there any other ways to do this, which will not require any Tomcat config changes. My situation is that I can't make Tomcat config changes easily but I can make as many changes as required to the actual web app.

Answer (score 0):

I got almost same error while launching Spring Boot 2 App.

I excluded `crimson.jar`, and it works.

ref. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#XML_Parsers_and_Java