# Migrate from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 9, page need reload/refresh to work

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have a crashed webserver running Tomcat 7. 
I installed Tomcat 9 (next next install) and Java 8u202. I just copied the webapps/kiosk directory from the old webserver to the new server.
When accessing the site localhost:8080/kiosk i get the following error.
But when I reload the page it works. I'm running the page in kioskmode (Chrome) and want it to autostart which is a problem with the error. 
Thanks in advance for the help.

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message AuthConfigFactory error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.SecurityException: AuthConfigFactory error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory.getFactory(AuthConfigFactory.java:85)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.findJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1239)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1232)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Root Cause

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:76)
    javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:67)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory.getFactory(AuthConfigFactory.java:66)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.findJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1239)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1232)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Root Cause

java.lang.SecurityException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://apache.org/xml/features/allow-java-encodings
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.PersistentProviderRegistrations.loadProviders(PersistentProviderRegistrations.java:65)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl.loadPersistentRegistrations(AuthConfigFactoryImpl.java:345)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl.<init>(AuthConfigFactoryImpl.java:68)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:76)
    javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:67)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory.getFactory(AuthConfigFactory.java:66)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.findJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1239)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1232)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Root Cause

org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://apache.org/xml/features/allow-java-encodings
    oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory.setFeature(JXSAXParserFactory.java:137)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.setFeature(Digester.java:504)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.PersistentProviderRegistrations.loadProviders(PersistentProviderRegistrations.java:61)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl.loadPersistentRegistrations(AuthConfigFactoryImpl.java:345)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl.<init>(AuthConfigFactoryImpl.java:68)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:76)
    javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:67)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory.getFactory(AuthConfigFactory.java:66)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.findJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1239)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1232)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.17
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this in another question, this works for me too.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944803/java-lang-securityexception-org-xml-sax-saxnotrecognizedexception-feature-htt#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944803/java-lang-securityexception-org-xml-sax-saxnotrecognizedexception-feature-htt#_=_)

add the following properties to TOMCAT_HOME/conf/catalina.properties:

javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl